# Can't pod install on React Native 0.61.5 new project

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, glog

I'm facing a bizarre error, I just created a new React Native project with react-native init AwesomeProject --version 0.61.5 but it failed during the pod install part. I tried to pod install after too but this occurs when installing glog:

```
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk accepts -g... yes
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk option to accept ISO C89... unsupported
checking whether /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
/Users/nicknish/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/nicknish/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/nicknish/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

The config.log file is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/0Qse7puf.
I tried a lot of things that I found online, but none was able to fix the problem. This problems occur in every project when installing glog. Anyone has any idea what it could be? A friend of mine was able to start a new project, maybe it is an enviroment issue.

**UPDATE:** I had this line on my .zshrc file:
`export CPATH="$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"`
I removed it and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Xcode ->preference ->location
in that select command line tools : 'your xcode version '

Answer (score 2):

try sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

Answer (score 0):

[image: Xcode-Settings-Location]

Navigate to `Xcode > Settings > Location`

Set `Command Line Tools` to Xcode version.